# IE8 incompatibility with position:relative and others

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have this web: http://81.35.152.41:8888/ca/dinamic/coleccions

Web is draw well in Opera, Chrome, Safari, Firefox...

In ie8 menu and all positions are bad....

What can I do to draw well in ie8 ?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You are using HTML5 elements, which IE8 might not recognize. Try using [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).